# How to use Wildcard in Numpy array operations?

Tags: python, numpy

For instance, define a numpy array with `numpy.str_` format and doing the replace operation supported by `numpy.char`:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array(['a-b-c-d','e-f-g-h'],np.str_)
print (np.char.replace(a,'*-','i-'))
```

The returned result would be `['a-b-c-d', 'e-f-g-h']` but `['i-i-i-d', 'i-i-i-h']` is expected.

Answer (score 3):

Is there any reason to use numpy arrays? You can't use wildcards with `numpy.char.replace`.

I would suggest to use python lists here and the `re` module:

```
l = ['a-b-c-d', 'e-f-g-h']
import re
out = [re.sub('.-', 'i-', i) for i in l]
```

Output: `['i-i-i-d', 'i-i-i-h']`